# You don't have permission to access /on this server

Tags: mod-rewrite, mod-security, security

I created a form in joomla with 2000 fields but when I submit the form it gives me:
error-- You don't have permission to access /en/soccer-player-update on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I also increase the php.ini and shuhosin extension values related to post data but unable to find the error.

It may be mod_security issue? or any?

Comment: did you enable modsecurity? what about httpd logs?

Comment: You really need to provide more information

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes in your Apache config file

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
By default, your global directory settings is (httpd.conf line ~188):

```
 <Directory />
 Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 Order deny,allow
 Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

set the options to : Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

Finally, it should look like:

```
 <Directory />
 #Options FollowSymLinks
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

Comment: But httpd.conf is not accessible from my end? Please suggest.

Comment: are you using shared server?

Comment: yes.using shared server